# Create nuget package which doesn't depend on a specific version of a dependency

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, roslyn-code-analysis

We have a custom Code Analyzers nuget package which references specific versions of `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`, `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` & `System.Collections.Immutable`. Our nuget package is currently failing to emit build errors -> when I check the build log I can see that there is a missing binding redirect as the following is outputted:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

I can verify this by adding the following binding redirect and it works: `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.9.0" newVersion="2.6.0.0" />`.

`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` is not referenced directly by any project in the solution so I am confused as to why this even works - I can't see another version in the `bin`, either.

I don't want to have to add a binding redirect to each project in our solution (there are over 50). Is there a way to bundle the redirect with the nuget package? Or else have it depend on a range of versions so that it is not even necessary..?